# content appearing below div instead of in it

Tags: html

I'm a newbie to html, I'm trying to put some orange text into a white box with an orange border. I've got:

```html
<div style="
    top: 20px; 
    left: 110px; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 3; 
    visibility: show;
    width: 45px;
    height: 15px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border-color: #E2943C;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;">

    <p>
       <font size="-1" color="#E2943C" face="Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif"> Beta </font>
    </p>
</div>
```

For some reason, the text is showing up beneath the box instead of in it. I'm sure it is some simple stupid  error, but I can't seem to pinpoint it - does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `top: 20px;` in conjunction with `position: absolute;` will push the contents 20px down.

Comment: The font tag was deprecated somewhere around 1867.

Comment: It doesn't in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rEJVG/. Have you got some other classes being applied? - Look in fiddler or use inspect element.

Comment: @JonEgerton - uncheck normalized css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply `margin:0px` on `p` tag, it should work
Your div height is small that is why text is falling down due default to margin of `p`

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, just a cleanup of the spaghetti.

First of all, get that inline styling out of the markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/uA94u/

Now its easier to read the code:

```
<div class="content">
  <p>Beta</p>  
</div>​

.content 
{ 
    top: 20px; 
    left: 110px; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 3; 
    visibility: show;
    width: 45px;
    height: 15px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #E2943C;
}

p
{
    font-size:1em;
    color:#E2943C;
    font-face:Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **inline styling** is an **outdated** way of styling your elements. I think a few tutorials should help get you going in the right direction.

The way to style elements is to either link a **CSS(Cascading Style Sheet)** file to the document or **embed** the styling using the  tag.

Here is a more accepted version:

http://jsfiddle.net/FvC9n/

If you would like some tutorials then ask and I can show you some links.

A good place to start (if you can cope without videos) is http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp it is targeted at beginners, beware, do not take what it says as the law.

Answer (score 1):

Make your font `line-height` to exactly the height of the division (15 px) and it will be in vertically center. Plus adding `text-align:center;` will make it horizontally center.

Add these css attributes to your paragraph css. Have a look at this [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tUarp/)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome the text appeared outside the box while in IE8 it appeared correct.
Apply the following:

```
<style>
    .divClass {
        top: 20px; 
        left: 110px; 
        z-index: 3; 
        width:50px;
        background:#FFFFFF;
        border-color: #E2943C;
        border-style: solid;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-left-width: 1px;
        border-right-width: 1px
    }
    </style> 

    <div
       class="divClass">

      <p> 
        <font size="-1" color="#E2943C" face="Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif"> Beta </font> </p>  
    </div>
```